# Mixed boundary value problems for Heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

This might be a very simple question, but basically I am looking for a good reference for studying the heat equation on Riemannian manifolds with boundary, specifically when data is put on lateral sides of the boundary. A more precise formulation is given below.

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact smooth Riemannian manifold with a smooth boundary. Let $T>0$, let $V\in C^{\infty}([0,T]\times M)$ and consider the heat equation with boundary data $f$:
\begin{equation}\label{pf0}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u-\Delta_g u+Vu=0\,\quad &\text{on $(0,T)\times M$},
\\
u=f\,\quad &\text{on $\Sigma=(0,T)\times \partial M$,}\\
u(0,x)=0 \,\quad &\text{on $M$,}
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I haven't found any references for regularity of solutions to this rather standard PDE with $f$ in Sobolev spaces. Can something precise be said about the regularity of solutions, say if $f \in H^k_0(\Sigma)$ for $k>0$ or perhaps when $f \in H^r_0(0,T;H^s(\partial M))$?